Wonder who bought the GENESIS Block?
So.  I bought into the block system years ago.  Verified it and forgot my code for the longest time finally came across it after logging into my blox paks account.  Then again on polygonscan and then etherscan.   It reverted me to the new site and wouldn’t let me re register from the beginning.   Did not mean to sell anything on purpose.  I was just trying to verify myself.
